# "Random Article" Feature on wikipedia.com

Tags: random, wiki

i would like to know what algorithm and what programming language wikipedia is using to randomly choose an article to display.

i would also like to know how does it work so fast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Village_pump_%28technical%29/Archive_46#Is_.27Random_article.27_truly_random.3F)  information on that.

> Every article is assigned a random number between 0 and 1 when it is created (these are indexed in SQL, which is what makes selection fast). When you click random article it generates a target random number and then returns the article whose recorded random number is closest to this target.

If you are interested you can read the actual code [here](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/specials/SpecialRandompage.php?view=markup).

Comment: how does it return the article whose recorded random number is closest to this target? do you think it sorts the entire table first?

Comment: I guess the table is sorted, yes. This way, you can insert and find items very fast (should be O(log(N)) using binary search.

Comment: If it's sorted the sorted table will be kept and new articles will be integrated into it somehow.

Answer (score 3):

[Something along this lines](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phpwiki/newcodebase/SpecialRandompage.php?revision=1164&view=markup):

```
 "SELECT cur_id,cur_title
        FROM cur USE INDEX (cur_random)
        WHERE cur_namespace=0 AND cur_is_redirect=0
        AND cur_random>RAND()
        ORDER BY cur_random
        LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MediaWiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org):

> MediaWiki is a free software wiki
>   package written in **PHP**, originally
>   for use on Wikipedia. It is now used
>   by several other projects of the
>   non-profit Wikimedia Foundation and by
>   many other wikis, including this
>   website, the home of MediaWiki.

MediaWiki is open source, so you can download the code and inspect it, to see how they have implemented this feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the source](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/phase3/includes/specials/SpecialRandompage.php?view=markup), they use PHP/MySQL a sort and filter pages by pregenerated random values (`page_random` column) that have an index on them.